# Simulate Geometric Brownian Motion Path with Fixed Starting AND Ending Points

Tags: simulation, brownian-motion

It is straightforward to simulate GBM path from a set starting value, but what if I also want it to arrive at a certain value in the end? Any ideas on how to do it are highly appreciated.

Comment: This is based on a [Brownian Bridge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=brownian+bridge): you merely have to exponentiate it.